# pip3 failed to build ueberzug

Tags: python-3.x, pip

I've installed `python3-dev` `wheel` but I get this error when `pip3 install ueberzug`

```
Collecting ueberzug
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/6d/37/2b64d32a28f704309a1ea8353c6975ad5cf1045dd99ec47bf1f3b69bf0c1/ueberzug-18.1.9.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: python-xlib in ./.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from ueberzug) (0.29)
Requirement already satisfied: pillow in ./.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from ueberzug) (8.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: docopt in ./.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from ueberzug) (0.6.2)
Requirement already satisfied: attrs>=18.2.0 in ./.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from ueberzug) (20.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.10.0 in ./.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from python-xlib->ueberzug) (1.15.0)
Building wheels for collected packages: ueberzug
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for ueberzug: started
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for ueberzug: finished with status 'error'
  Complete output from command /usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-ylsjxvsy/ueberzug/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-wz813yvx --python-tag cp37:
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.linux-i686-3.7
  creating build/lib.linux-i686-3.7/ueberzug
  copying ueberzug/xutil.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.7/ueberzug
  copying ueberzug/version.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.7/ueberzug
  copying ueberzug/ui.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.7/ueberzug
  copying ueberzug/tmux_util.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.7/ueberzug
  copying ueberzug/thread.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.7/ueberzug
  copying ueberzug/terminal.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.7/ueberzug
  copying ueberzug/scaling.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.7/ueberzug
  copying ueberzug/query_windows.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.7/ueberzug
  copying ueberzug/process.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.7/ueberzug
  copying ueberzug/pattern.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.7/ueberzug
  copying ueberzug/parser.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.7/ueberzug
  copying ueberzug/loading.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.7/ueberzug
  copying ueberzug/library.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.7/ueberzug
  copying ueberzug/layer.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.7/ueberzug
  copying ueberzug/geometry.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.7/ueberzug
  copying ueberzug/files.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.7/ueberzug
  copying ueberzug/conversion.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.7/ueberzug
  copying ueberzug/batch.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.7/ueberzug
  copying ueberzug/action.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.7/ueberzug
  copying ueberzug/__main__.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.7/ueberzug
  copying ueberzug/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.7/ueberzug
  creating build/lib.linux-i686-3.7/ueberzug/lib
  copying ueberzug/lib/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.7/ueberzug/lib
  creating build/lib.linux-i686-3.7/ueberzug/lib/v0
  copying ueberzug/lib/v0/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.7/ueberzug/lib/v0
  running egg_info
  writing ueberzug.egg-info/PKG-INFO
  writing dependency_links to ueberzug.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
  writing entry points to ueberzug.egg-info/entry_points.txt
  writing requirements to ueberzug.egg-info/requires.txt
  writing top-level names to ueberzug.egg-info/top_level.txt
  reading manifest file 'ueberzug.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
  reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
  writing manifest file 'ueberzug.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
  copying ueberzug/lib/lib.sh -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.7/ueberzug/lib
  running build_ext
  building 'Xshm' extension
  creating build/temp.linux-i686-3.7
  creating build/temp.linux-i686-3.7/Xshm
  i686-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I/usr/include/python3.7m -c Xshm/Xshm.c -o build/temp.linux-i686-3.7/Xshm/Xshm.o
  Xshm/Xshm.c:7:10: fatal error: X11/extensions/XShm.h: No existe el fichero o el directorio
   #include <X11/extensions/XShm.h>
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  compilation terminated.
  error: command 'i686-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
  
  ----------------------------------------
  Running setup.py clean for ueberzug
Failed to build ueberzug
Installing collected packages: ueberzug
  Running setup.py install for ueberzug: started
    Running setup.py install for ueberzug: finished with status 'error'
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-ylsjxvsy/ueberzug/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-record-y8ogh7kn/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --user --prefix=:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-i686-3.7
    creating build/lib.linux-i686-3.7/ueberzug
    copying ueberzug/xutil.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.7/ueberzug
    copying ueberzug/version.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.7/ueberzug
    copying ueberzug/ui.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.7/ueberzug
    copying ueberzug/tmux_util.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.7/ueberzug
    copying ueberzug/thread.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.7/ueberzug
    copying ueberzug/terminal.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.7/ueberzug
    copying ueberzug/scaling.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.7/ueberzug
    copying ueberzug/query_windows.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.7/ueberzug
    copying ueberzug/process.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.7/ueberzug
    copying ueberzug/pattern.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.7/ueberzug
    copying ueberzug/parser.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.7/ueberzug
    copying ueberzug/loading.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.7/ueberzug
    copying ueberzug/library.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.7/ueberzug
    copying ueberzug/layer.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.7/ueberzug
    copying ueberzug/geometry.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.7/ueberzug
    copying ueberzug/files.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.7/ueberzug
    copying ueberzug/conversion.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.7/ueberzug
    copying ueberzug/batch.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.7/ueberzug
    copying ueberzug/action.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.7/ueberzug
    copying ueberzug/__main__.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.7/ueberzug
    copying ueberzug/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.7/ueberzug
    creating build/lib.linux-i686-3.7/ueberzug/lib
    copying ueberzug/lib/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.7/ueberzug/lib
    creating build/lib.linux-i686-3.7/ueberzug/lib/v0
    copying ueberzug/lib/v0/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.7/ueberzug/lib/v0
    running egg_info
    writing ueberzug.egg-info/PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to ueberzug.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
    writing entry points to ueberzug.egg-info/entry_points.txt
    writing requirements to ueberzug.egg-info/requires.txt
    writing top-level names to ueberzug.egg-info/top_level.txt
    reading manifest file 'ueberzug.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
    writing manifest file 'ueberzug.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    copying ueberzug/lib/lib.sh -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.7/ueberzug/lib
    running build_ext
    building 'Xshm' extension
    creating build/temp.linux-i686-3.7
    creating build/temp.linux-i686-3.7/Xshm
    i686-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I/usr/include/python3.7m -c Xshm/Xshm.c -o build/temp.linux-i686-3.7/Xshm/Xshm.o
    Xshm/Xshm.c:7:10: fatal error: X11/extensions/XShm.h: No existe el fichero o el directorio
     #include <X11/extensions/XShm.h>
              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'i686-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
    
    ----------------------------------------
```

Comment: Did you check the [dependencies](https://github.com/seebye/ueberzug#dependencies) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick googled search of the error message `#include <X11/extensions/XShm.h>` revealed that you're missing the package `libxext-dev`, install it with the command `sudo apt install libxext-dev`.

Answer (score 0):

my bad, I'm an idiot. I was missing a dependency, I've installed ueberzug on my other machine and I thought I had the dev packages but no. It is successfully installed now